# Creating a Histogram with Plot Data (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am a student programmer attempting to plot a histogram.

I have following sample histogram data.

```
V1  V2
214 6
215 6
216 6
217 5
218 5
219 6
220 5
221 6
222 6
223 6
224 6
225 6
226 6
227 7
228 7
229 7
230 7
231 8
232 8
233 8
234 8
235 8
```

The first column being what number is repeated and the second is the amount of repeats.

Currently, I am trying `ggplot(df, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_bar()` and I am not producing a graph.

I am probably overlooking an option. How would you plot this histogram?

Thank you

Comment: Bar chart would great but I get the errors. 'Error: Unknown parameters: binwidth, bins, origin, right'

Comment: `ggplot(df, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: With geom_bar(), could you do a pseudo bin?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the name of your variable into this code.

```
 hist(VARIABLE_NAME, 
      main="Histogram of XYZ", 
      xlab="X access", 
      border="blue", 
      col="green",
      xlim=c(100,700),
      las=1, 
      breaks=5)
```

Comment: I am using a data frame with two variables. I am trying to make it with two vectors

Comment: I was wondering about that, I thought that the first vector was the row number because it descends in value. Do you have the prior code? I think where you have aes it should be factor and you should have 1 -  ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(V1))) + geom_bar(stat = "bin")

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the code for this data. I just updated the data to make it more clear. How would you feed V2 ( the frequency to the plot)?

Comment: I am getting the error Error in .Call.graphics(C_palette2, .Call(C_palette2, NULL)) : 
  invalid graphics state

Comment: what about ggplot(df, aes(x=(V1), y=V2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

Comment: That works! Is there a way to bin the data? I think I am overplotting (I have >600000 bars now )

Comment: I think that might have to do with breaks.

Comment: + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 20)) see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818899/r-ggplot-y-axis-breaks-settings it gives a great presentation on how ggplots works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the repeat function in order to get all of the data fleshed out

```
Data <- rep(V1, each = V2)
hist(Data)
```

This should do what you want it to and its simple and should be fast