# Sorting y axis when it is not specified

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am newbie trying to make a chart with more values placed on y axis and I have been searchign a lot how to do it. sadly no explanation is good for my case and I think it is because I am not specyfying Y-axis. I tried things like scale_y_continous but to no avail.

Here is my chart:

```
ggplot(wyzwania,aes(forcats::fct_infreq(Jakie.sa.Twoim.zdaniem.najwieksze.wyzwania.dla.nauczycieli.zwiazane.z.przejsciem.do.nauki.online.zdalnej.), fill= as.factor(Jakie.sa.Twoim.zdaniem.najwieksze.wyzwania.dla.nauczycieli.zwiazane.z.przejsciem.do.nauki.online.zdalnej.))) +       
  geom_bar() + 
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size=18),
        axis.text.x=element_blank())+
  scale__continuous(limits = c(-5000, 5000))+
labs(title = "Wykres przedstawiajacy opinie ankietowanych o wyzwaniach stawianych przed nauczycielami", x="Stopien edukacji", y="Liczba odpowiedzi", fill="Wyzwania stawiane przed nauczycielami")+
  facet_wrap(~wyzwania$Etap.edukacji)
```

And here is how it looks like:
[image: 1]

I would like it to show values every 2 if possible.

Comment: What you mean by "show values every 2"? Do you want the breaks of the y-axis to be 0, 2, 4, ...?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I meant I forgot to write breaks sorry

Comment: The breaks argument allows a vector of breakpoints so something like this should work, but it's not dynamic if your data changes. `scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(from=0,to=16,by=2))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting y axis breaks in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818899/setting-y-axis-breaks-in-ggplot)