# Add More Values To X Axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I understand there are similar questions with answers already, but they are not helping. At least it's not working for me.

Right now, my x axis is only showing 30, 35, 40, 45, 50.

[image]

DESIRED OUTCOME:
I want my x axis to show each number between 30 and 50. Each box and wisker plot should have it's corresponding week number displaying on the x axis.

BONUS: How can i declutter my current labels??

Here is what's making the plot

```
p <- ggplot(data=pos1, aes(x=Week.Number, y=Total.Positives, group =Week.Number,label 
     =Total.Positives)) + 
     geom_boxplot() 
 
p1 <- p + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(30,50)) +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90 , vjust =0.5)) +
       geom_text_repel(aes(label = Total.Positives)) 

print(p1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Setting y axis breaks in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818899/setting-y-axis-breaks-in-ggplot)

Comment: YES @stefan THANK YOU

Comment: Okay I apologize @GregorThomas, I will listen to you because you have helped me so much in the past. 

I'm just an eager noobie. I hope to be as wise as you guys one day